# Does Meteor have a distinct query for collections?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'd like to return distinct fields in my collection. I know these are the [docs for mongo operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/), but I'm not familiar enough with the query language to know if this is possible?

```
Meteor.publish("distinctCollection", function() {
    return Collection.find({ ... }, fields: { "myField": 1 });
});
```

Comment: Check this neat solution [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct

Answer (score 10):

```
Collection.find({}).distinct('myField', true);
```

To use, put the following in [project]/client/lib/a.js:

```
LocalCollection.Cursor.prototype.distinct = function (key,random) {
  var self = this;

  if (self.db_objects === null)
    self.db_objects = self._getRawObjects(true);
  if (random)
    self.db_objects = _.shuffle(self.db_objects);
  if (self.reactive)
    self._markAsReactive({ordered: true,
                          added: true,
                          removed: true,
                          changed: true,
                          moved: true});
  var res = {};
  _.each(self.db_objects,function(value){

    if(!res[value[key]]){
        res[value[key]] = value;
    }
  });
  return _.values(res);
};
```

Comment: using this am I able to make a custom `find()` to make certain operations reactive only? So its only reactive on added and removed?

Comment: yes. in self._markAsReactive() set false: ordered, changed, moved.

Comment: Seems like self._markAsReactive() doesn't work anymore. Trying to dig in and find what it's called now.

Comment: It's called _depend, I *think*, but it's not really working like I expect anyway. Not like Mongo's distinct. I'm just going to roll my own.

Comment: `LocalCollection.Cursor` is undefined for me. (Yes, I replaced `LocalCollection`)

Comment: @JonatanLittke After release of 0.6.5.1 all globals were put to Packages object. You can reach LocalCollection by typing `Package.minimongo.LocalCollection.Cursor`.

Comment: After 0.6.5.1 the above solution doesn't work. Check this instead:
https://github.com/jhoxray/meteor-mongo-extensions or package on meteorite : https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/mongodb-aggregation