# Meteor: how to search for only distinct field values aka a collection.distinct("fieldname") similar to Mongo's

Tags: meteor, distinct

I'm using Meteor, and I'm trying to find only distinct (unique) values of a field.
Mongodb has the command

```
Collection.distinct("fieldname");
```

but it's not implemented in the Meteor driver for Mongo. 
I've tried using the meteor-mongo-extensions package but still got an "undefined" on the client console for a client-side `Collection.distinct("fieldname");`

what, essentially, is a distinct looking for?

I feel like someone this is such a basic query- like for example a list of students with their teacher as a field, and then making a list of students by teachers out of that, for example...

if I can just wrap my lazy errant brain around the general concept I can probably bash something workable out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just use underscore.js, which comes with Meteor - should be fine for the suggested use case.  You might run into performance problems if you try this on a vast data set or run it repeatedly, but it should be adequate for common-or-garden usage:

```
var distinctEntries = _.uniq(Collection.find({}, {
    sort: {myField: 1}, fields: {myField: true}
}).fetch().map(function(x) {
    return x.myField;
}), true);
```

That will return the distinct entries in `myField` for all documents in `Collection`. Apologies if the one-liner looks a bit unwieldy; the `sort` and `fields` options and the `true` flag are just to make it more efficient.

Comment: great idea. thanks. bonus that it's underscore. i need to look into underscore more and stop being shy of it, as you point out, it comes with meteor.

Comment: yeah actually the more i look at `_.uniq` the more i like it- wrapping a find like that. what's the performance issue you mentioned due to?

Comment: to be honest, i'm no mongo expert so it might be nothing, but i would assume that an internal mongo method would do something more elegant than loading the entire query set into memory, iterating through it and returning an array. easy to imagine how the mongo method could be far more memory-efficient than that.

Comment: that makes sense. 
hey, i ended up banging around until this code worked
`uniqueTeachers: function() {
 var everything = myCollection.find().fetch();
 var justTeacherNames = _.pluck(everything,"teacherName");
 return _.uniq(justTeacherNames);`
any idea why the standard meteor way of 
`myCollection.find({}, {fields:{teacherName:1}}).fetch();`
was borking but the _.pluck worked?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but it's doing exactly what the map method does, and probably more efficiently knowing underscore. Not sure why map doesn't work for you, but if that solution does then I'd just run with it.

Comment: Meteor collection cursors have their own [map function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map) so  no need for `fetch()` just `Collection.find({}).map( function(x) {return x.myField;})`.

Comment: Per @user728291: `_.uniq(Courses.find({}).map( function(x) {return x.fullName;}));`

Comment: But this solution isn't reactive right (e.g. if you were using it in a publication definition)?  I'm trying to figure out how to do something like while using `publish-composite`.

Answer (score 9):

If you'd prefer to do this on the server and thus save client memory and bandwidth try this aggregator package. It wraps mongodb's "distinct" function. https://github.com/zvictor/meteor-mongo-server/

Comment: Tried that on MacOSX and got => Errors while adding packages:             
                                              
While checking for zvictor:mongodb-server-aggregation@1.0.4:
error: No compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the package author and ask them to publish it for your platform.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/monbro/meteor-mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation/ has had more update love, forked from zvictor's.  It's a lot more popular on atmosphere.

Comment: @Philippe see above package: `meteor add monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation`

Answer (score 8):

A Non-Underscore, pure mongo solution would be to access the raw collection directly. This involves a Promise (though you can use `await` to await the resolved value).

Note: it will run on the MongoDB server and return distinct values to the client.

```
Collection._collection.rawCollection().distinct('fieldname').then(distinctValues => console.log(distinctValues))
```

Comment: Any idea what is the best way to use mongo's distinct in the client as the rawCollection is only present on the server side? The `_collection` is not present in meteor 1.11 ...? and using the collection's rawCollection() function is only possible on the server

Comment: @PeterT. You can't do this on the client as the "mini mongo" only has a subset of the Mongo functions. The only way to do this is to "fetch" all the data on the client and then use Javascript.

Comment: alright then. It should be possible to provide the unique data as a subscription to avoid sending everything to the client tough. Hm, in my case now, it shouldn't be too much I guess ...

Answer (score 6):

Improving richsilv's answer:

```js
function distinct(collection, field) {
  return _.uniq(collection.find({}, {
    sort: {[field]: 1}, fields: {[field]: 1}
  }).fetch().map(x => x[field]), true);
}
```

How to use:

```js
var arrResults = distinct(MyCollection, 'myfield');
```

Comment: i admire this solution, and i would suggest adding `dinstinct(..,.., condition){ if (!condition) condition = {} ` to be used in `collection.find(condition) ...}`