# Meteor: How to show distinct field values from a collection in a select dropdown?

Tags: meteor, distinct

I'm building a Meteor app where I have a collection with products. Each document in that collection has two fields: productName and productCategory. In my app I want to show all products for a given category. So I have a select field where I want to select a category. After pushing the search button I want to show a list with all products for the given category.

In my template I have the following code to create the select field

```
<select>
{{#each distinct_products}}
<option>{{productCategory}}</option>
{{/each}}
<select>
```

In my js file, the definition of distinct_product is as follow:

```
Template.templatename.distinct_products = function() {
 var distinctEntries = _.uniq(Meteor.products.find({}, {sort: {productCategory:1}, fields: {productCategory:true}}).fetch().map(function(x) {
 return x.productCategory;
 }), true);
 return distinctEntries;
};
```

I found this solution in the following topic: [Meteor: how to search for only distinct field values aka a collection.distinct("fieldname") similar to Mongo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct)

However, My select field shows a number of options equal as the number of unique product categories, but it are empty values (no text). Thus, my select fields has a number of empty options and no product category is showed.

I suppose there is something wrong with the type of the returned value in my JS function, but I don't know what. Can someone put me on the right path please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_.uniq` block will return an array of `productCategory` properties, which is what your`{{#each}` block is iterating over - so you shouldn't be specifying `{{productCategory}}` again in your template.

Change this:

```
<option>{{productCategory}}</option>
```

to:

```
<option>{{this}}</option>
```

and it should work.  By trying to access `{{productCategory}}` within the loop, you are in effect asking for `product.productCategory.productCategory`, which is going to be empty; `product.productCategory` is already being returned by your helper.

As a side note, `_.pluck` is designed as a more concise version what you're using `_.map` for, so it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to shorten it

```
var wow = _.uniq(_.pluck(Nodes.find().fetch(),"productCategory"));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11396205)

Comment: I don't know why I but it seems like not a lot of people like new people on here. I would definitely leave a comment if I could. I only have 18 reputation. It takes 50 just to leave a comment. The only way to gain reputation at this point is answering, asking my own questions. And voting. I understand what you are saying but please give new people a chance to gain enough points to even do what you request of them.