# How do I return only unique collection fields from a Meteor collection?

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I have a really simple to-do app where users enter a to-do and a tag then submit. When I click a tag on the left side, it displays the to-do that is associated with it. I would like to filter the list on the left side by unique tags. I can't seem to find it anywhere. Any help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuJmk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ic6Q.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works:

```
Template.all.helpers({
    linkList: function() {
    var everything = *yourCollection*.find().fetch();
     var *yourUniqueFieldItems* = _.pluck(everything,"*YourField*");
      return _.uniq(*yourUniqueFieldItems*);
    },
```

The top voted answer here: [Meteor: how to search for only distinct field values aka a collection.distinct("fieldname") similar to Mongo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct) doesn't work, but the author of that post found a solution himself. Unfortunately, it's buried in the comments and it's not the actual answer.