# Category appearing twice while using mongo with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am doin a simple app in Meteor a Todo app .

I have a collection and its helper functions defined in isClient section.

```
ToDo = new Meteor.Collection('todo');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.categoryList.helpers({
    category: function(){
        return ToDo.find({},{sort: {cat: 1}});;
    }   
  });
  Template.todo.helpers({
    list: function(){
        return ToDo.find();
    }
```

My template file looks like following

```
<template name="categoryList">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
        {{#each category}}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{cat}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<template name="todo">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
        {{#each list}}
        <!--<li class="list-group-item">{{tasks}}</li>-->
        <div class="checkbox {{selectedClass}}">
            <label>
                <input class="{{selectedClass}}" type="checkbox" value=""> {{tasks}}
            </label>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

The problem I am having is , the categories are getting displayed twice on 
[image: categories appearing twice]

The data is getting inserted as follows:

```
ToDo.insert({cat:"Home",tasks:"Clean home"})
```

Please provide me some insights on it .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning documents from the same collection, so there are three 'items' in the list, and therefore three 'categories' being listed. You are listing the equivalent category for each 'item' in the list rather than a list of unique categories.

```
Template.categoryList.helpers({
    category: function(){
        return ToDo.find({},{sort: {cat: 1}}); // This is the ToDo collection
    }   
});
Template.todo.helpers({
    list: function(){
        return ToDo.find(); // This is also the same ToDo collection
}
```

You are returning the exact same documents from the same collection, just ordering them differently and outputting different fields from the same documents.

You need to find the 'distinct' values: [Meteor: how to search for only distinct field values aka a collection.distinct("fieldname") similar to Mongo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct)

So, just change your `category` helper to this as per above reference:

```
Template.categoryList.helpers({
    category: function(){
        var distinctCategories = _.uniq(ToDo.find({}, {
            sort: {cat: 1}, fields: {cat: true}
        }).fetch().map(function(doc) {
            return doc.cat;
        }), true);
        return distinctCategories;
    }   
});
```

Or you need to store the categories in their own collection, then reference them from the todo items separately (usually by referencing the _id).

**update:** We can remove the fetch call and do the following :

```
Template.categoryList.helpers({
    category: function(){
        var distinctCategories = _.uniq(ToDo.find({}, {
            sort: {cat: 1}, fields: {cat: true}
        }).map( function(doc) {return doc.cat;
        }), true);
        return distinctCategories;
    }   

});
```

And the iterator wont display the data since the .map function returns an array, So we can do the following in the category template:

```
<template name="categoryList">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
        {{#each category }}

        <li class="list-group-item">{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I really am confused with this mongo db stuff , can ya throw some code which can explain it in a more detailed way . Plz

Comment: I thought its wrong to create two collection tables for category and items .I was in the impression that its the sql way , and I have seen complex schemas on mongo website like these .

Comment: Yes, you're right. Normalising the schema is typical of SQL, but you can still use it for NoSQL. The general wisdom is to structure your data based on it's most frequent use, which is typically reading from, rather than writing to. So denormalised makes sense for your case, like you have chosen. I was just offering an alternative.

Comment: collection.distinct returns type error , so I guess its not yet supported in meteor . So I have to find some other way to do it

Comment: Yep, it's not yet supported. Read the link I posted, and also see my updated answer.

Comment: .map function returns an array , and now its not displaying it with the current template iteration method ...