# Loading fields from collection into select field and filtering it based on selected value

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

Basically i have two questions which are related but i'll separate them with numbers
1) I am trying to load a single field into a select dropdown box from collection but its populating with all repetitive values it collected from the list below it instead of its own helper.

```
<template name="carsList">

{{> categoryFilter}}

<ul class="collection" id="listings">
{{#each cars}}
<li>
  {{> carItem}}
</li>
{{/each}}
 </ul>
</template>
```

category template is

```
<template name="categoryFilter">
 <div class="input-field">
 <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    {{#each companyCategories}}
     {{> companyCategory}}
    {{/each}}
 </select>
 <label>Select Category</label>
</div>
</template>

<template name="companyCategory">
  <option>{{ccategory}}</option>
</template>
```

categoryFilter is holding the dropdown template for which iam using the below helper

```
Template.categoryFilter.helpers({
companyCategories: function(){
return Cars.find();
}
});
```

instead of populating from its own helper its loading the data that is coming from "listings" below it and repeating data.

[Image of the result in selectbox](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=cd55053)

2) I also want to filter the listings based on the value selected in the select dropdown box (Ofcourse reactive)

Please help

**EDIT**

This is how my template looks now

```
<template name="categoryFilter">
 <div class="input-field">
  <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    {{#each companyCategories}}
      {{> companyCategory}}
    {{/each}}
   </select>
 <label>Select Category</label>
 </div>
</template>

<template name="companyCategory">
 <option>{{justCategory}}</option>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would proceed. First, the dropdown: you should use a cursor instead of an array of documents. So your helper should be:

```
Template.categoryFilter.helpers({
    companyCategories: function(){
       return Jobs.find();
    }
});
```

and your `categoryFilter` template HTML could be something like this

```
<template name="categoryFilter">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    {{selectedCategory}} <!-- refer to an helper which returns the reactive variable--> 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  {{#each companyCategories}}
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" class="categoryItem" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{yourCatergoryNameField}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

You can then create an event to record the current category selected in the dropdown when it is clicked

```
    "click .categoryItem": function(e, t) {
        var text = $(e.target).text()
        Session.set("selectedCategory", text)
    },
```

Now, you can filter your cars using the `selectedCategory` reactive variable. For this, you need another helper. It could be for instance:

```
Template.carList.helpers({
    carListingByCategory: function(){
       var filter = Session.get ("selectedCategory");
       return Car.find(category:filter)
    }
});
```

That should do the trick. I never use Session, so it might not work as I suppose it does. If it does not work, use [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) instead. Basically, you add `var pageSession = new ReactiveDict();` at the beginning of your doc and you can replace `Session` with `pageSession` in my code.

**EDIT**

Ok, let's have a try with underscore. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255779/3793161), here is what you can do to return all the distinct categories for every item of allJobs:

```
Template.categoryFilter.helpers({
    companyCategories: _.uniq(Collection.find({}, {
        sort: {myField: 1}, fields: {myField: true}
    }).fetch().map(function(x) {
        return x.myField;
    }), true);
    }
});
```

where `myfield` is your categories array field.

**EDIT 2**

Try to change your html and replace `{{justCategory}}`  with `{{this}}`:

```
<template name="categoryFilter">
 <div class="input-field">
  <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    {{#each companyCategories}}
      {{> companyCategory}}
    {{/each}}
   </select>
 <label>Select Category</label>
 </div>
</template>

<template name="companyCategory">
 <option>{{this}}</option>
</template>
```

Comment: Still the same result please look i updated my code and added an image to show the result iam getting. it is still loading the result that it is getting from the carItem template

Comment: try to put a `console.table(Jobs.find().fetch());`in the template rendered function. Do you see the repeated item there too? You probably have an issue with your publications. FYI, if two publications come from the same collection, they end up in the same collection client side too.

Comment: how many 1)collections 2) publications are you supposed to interact with in this page?

Comment: just one collection and two publications. i am going to have three filters like this for my app, which will be going to interact with the same collection and one publication that serves all the records

Comment: ok, then you must know that both publication will end up in the same collection client-side. I can't help more without having an idea of your collection structure/publications and what fields you are looking for (and where). You are sure that your collection does not have the duplicated items on the server as well? You can use robomongo to check this.

Comment: [Publication and Schema](https://jsfiddle.net/7efe95jc/) this is what i have as schema field. i just checked and there are duplicated items for this field. should i specify the values for filter in selectbox instead of showing retrieving them from collection? if yes how can i achieve it like compare from client list to collection values? Or is there any way i can make the repetive content to stop from being displayed and work on it?

Comment: can you paste in the fiddle your actual publications on server? i.e. the `Meteor.publish('singleJob',...` As far as I can tell (the fiddle), you have only one subscription (along with its publication) on your page.

Comment: I am sorry for that half code. now i uploaded all the publications and subscriptions. [publications](https://jsfiddle.net/7efe95jc/1/)

Comment: updated it. don't know why it was working without it also. how can i retrieve distinct values for the field ? because mongo's distinct  method doesn't work.

Comment: your way with "id" worked too. I just wasn't aware of it. I got an idea and  updated the answer.

Comment: Something I am not sure to understand: what do you want to use to populate your dropdown 1) all the job names (or any other field) of the documents of your collection or 2) a list of every distinct job category in your collection (for every document)? tell me before trying my fix in my edit (that will probably not work, all things considered) Moreover, if it is an autoform related problem, I wont be able to help (you should add auto-form tag to the question too)

Comment: yes a list of every distinct job category in my collection. and that too from alljobs publication. that singlejob publication is for displaying job details (same as single blog post) to the user . I want to populate dropdown from alljobs publication.

Comment: `Template.categoryFilter.helpers({
  companyCategories: function() {
    var everything = Jobs.find().fetch();
    var ccategory = _.pluck(everything,"ccategory");
    return _.uniq(ccategory);
  }
});` Iam using this solution from the same source.its rendering four li's as it is in schema but its not displaying the values. i can see just html li's but not appearing in the page.what should i do now?

Comment: `console.log(_.uniq(ccategory));` in your helper. Check if you get the values.

Comment: `var justCategory = _.uniq(ccategory)
    console.log(justCategory);
    return justCategory;` did this and in template i am calling `<option>{{justCategory}}</option>` but still i can see distinct values in console but not in the dropdown. just plain li's.

Comment: What do you need to send to autoform? If it is an array of values, this should be good. If it is a cursor, it is not. I assume you don't generate your objects using an `{{#each}}` , autoform does it for you?

Comment: Edited my question with the template I am using

Comment: That Worked. Thanks alot for being there to solve this. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. It was hard to figure out the good fix :-)

Comment: yes it was pretty hard. can you please explain a little about how the helper function variable wasn't returning values and why `{{this}}` returned them. i am new i can learn from this something.

Comment: Sure. The regular use case of  `{{#each xxx}}` uses a cursor. This is like a pipe to the database. But it wasn't the case here, your helper returns an array of documents. `{{this}}` is how you get an array item value.

Comment: So basically `fetch()` returns an array while `find()` returns a cursor right?

Comment: can you please look into this [Question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829105/dopdownlist-is-being-populated-with-limited-values-instead-of-values-from-total) i am stuck in this badly. @Billybobbonnet

Comment: I'll post an answer in a couple of hours, maybe before.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll wait for it.  You understood the situation clearly right?