# underscore.js - create array of unique items from objects embedded in a list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, underscore.js

I've been trying to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) in a [Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) project I'm working on, but can't seem to figure out how to transform a set of objects.

The objects look something like this (there's about 15k, but they all look like these two):

```js
 [{
   "_id": "a_0011223344",
   "taggedUsers": [{
     "id": 1122244453,
     "username": "john123"
   }],
   "field": "ABC"
 }, {
   "_id": "a_0011223345",
   "taggedUsers": [{
     "id": 1122244454,
     "username": "bill123"
   }, {
     "id": 1122244455,
     "username": "jim123"
   }],
   "field": "ABC"
 }]
```

Each object can have one or more `"taggedUsers"` objects, and I need a list of the unique `"taggedUsers.username"` fields.  Meteor does not support mongoDB's [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) function, so I am trying to use underscore.js instead (per what I've read and the reccomendation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct)).

In my server side console `db.myCollection.distinct("taggedUsers.username")` returns the desired result `["john123", "bill123", "jim123"]`, but I cannot replicate this in underscore.js.

I have been trying a combination of `_.each`, `_.map`, `_.pluck`, and `_.uniq`, but have been unsuccessful.  I think it may have something with the fields being in embedded objects, but am not sure.

Ideally I would like to return an array of objects looking like this:

```js
[{
  "id": 1122244453,
  "username": "john123",
  "field": "ABC"
}, {
  "id": 1122244454,
  "username": "bill123",
  "field": "ABC"
}, {
  "id": 1122244455,
  "username": "jim123",
  "field": "DEF"
}]
```

with just the `taggedUsers.username`, `taggedUsers.id`, and `field` feilds, and all duplicates removed, but would be happy if I could also just get an array of the `taggedUsers.usernames` like I am in the `db.colleciton.distinct()` function.

Ultimately it would be nice to know how to get the basic array, the array of unique objects, (or maybe even how to get the result of `db.collection.distinct()` in a template helper), but any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want an array of tagged users, but the example shows that you also have a `field: ABC` in them. Is that a typo?

Comment: The "field" in the parent object would be helpful too, let me edit the question to make it more clear @DavidWeldon

Comment: @DavidWeldon do you recommend trying to find an underscore.js solution, or should i try and run the mongo query on the server and calling it with a method?

Comment: It depends - are you publishing the docs to the client only to do this or do you need them on the client for some other reason? If they are already published, it will be faster to use underscore in a helper.

Comment: @DavidWeldon since there are so many I am only publishing 20-30 at a time per template.  Given that, I should probably run it on the server, but for educational purposes it would be awesome if you could show me how to do it in underscore ! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversation, it sounds like it would be better to compute this on the server via a method call. For educational purposes, here's how you could do it using underscore:

```
// Get an array of docs somehow
var docs = Collection.find().fetch();

var taggedUsers = _.chain(docs)
  .map(function(d) {
    // Copy the 'field' to each of the tagged users within a doc
    _.each(d.taggedUsers, function(user) {
      user.field = d.field;
    });
    return d;
  })
  .pluck('taggedUsers') // Extract only the tagged users arrays
  .flatten() // Flatten them into a single array
  .value();

// taggedUsers could look something like:
// [ { id: 1122244453, username: 'john123', field: 'ABC' },
//   { id: 1122244454, username: 'bill123', field: 'ABC' },
//   { id: 1122244455, username: 'jim123', field: 'ABC' },
//   { id: 1122244453, username: 'john123', field: 'ABC' } ]

// Compute a unique lists of tagged users, where the docs are unique by id
var utu = _.uniq(taggedUsers, false, function(user) {return user.id;});
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the correct approach with underscore, but my console is returning `taggedUsers` and `utu` as empty arrays.  My query looks like this: `Collection.find({"taggedUsers": {"$exists": true}}, {fields: { _id: 1, field: 1, "taggedUsers.username": 1, "taggedUsers.id": 1}}).fetch();` if that helps.  I think the error has something to do with quotes around `"taggedUsers.id"` and `"taggedUsers.username"`, but could be wrong.

Comment: Make sure `docs` has something in it. I tested the code with the examples you provided and it worked. Maybe just try `var docs = Collection.find({taggedUsers: {$exists: true}}).fetch()`. (assuming `Collection` is replaced by your actual collection name).

Comment: Looking like this: http://imgur.com/55tYWnz. Obviously don't think that your solution doesn't work, but am not sure what I am missing.  is `.field` supposed to be the `field` field (i.e. ABC, DEF), or a way to get values for `user` and `d`?  Also, what is `d` supposed to represent? Thanks!

Comment: `d` is a single document in the `docs` array. `user` is a single element of the `taggedUsers` array. What do you get if you `console.log(docs[0])`? Maybe your structure is different from the one used in the example. Do you have a test repo that I can see? I need to run but I'll check back on this in a little while.

Comment: Here is the printout of the `[0]` object in the console, and in mongol: http://imgur.com/NeMzFhW.  Going to keep working on this, but glad you got back to me ! I've read your blog before so it was cool running into you here, thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay the updated answer should work now. The problem was I needed `map` instead of an `each`. The previous answer worked in a non-meteor environment with an updated version of underscore. Sadly, meteor uses a really old version of underscore, so sometimes there are inconsistencies. That's what I get for not trying it in a meteor environment to begin with.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.  What dev environment do you usually work in? Your blog seems prettty meteor heavy? But thanks again for the help !!