# Meteor Distinct Values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, distinct

how I get distinct values from a find().fetch() function. I try this but this is not working. Anyone who see the mistake in my code?

```
var finales = UserSpieler.find({UserID: 1}).map(function(doc)
    {
      return doc.SpielerID;
    });

    var distinctArray = _.uniq(finales, false, function(d) {return d.SpielerID});
    var disctinctValues = _.pluck(distinctArray, 'SpielerID');

    return disctinctValues;
```

Thanks

Comment: You have already mapped the documents to their `SpielerID` in the `map` function, so you don't need to do so twice more in the other functions (simply pass it to `_.uniq`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues with what you are doing:

1)  `UserSpieler.find({UserID: 1})` returns only documents where UserId is 1. 
Instead it seems like you are trying to filter the fields.

So  `UserSpieler.find({},{UserID: 1})` which searches through all the documents.

2)  You are trying to pluck/map three different times. First, with `.map`. Second, with the mapping function in `._uniq`. Third, when calling `._pluck`.

Here's a fix to do the same thing

```
var finales = UserSpieler.find({},{UserID: 1}).map(function(doc)
  {
     return doc.SpielerID;
  }
);
var distinctArray = _.uniq(finales, false);
return distinctArray;
```

Also checkout the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254699/meteor-how-to-search-for-only-distinct-field-values-aka-a-collection-distinct)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, and as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23280241/2260775) answer, you can also use [this](http://github.com/monbro/meteor-mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation) package which adds distinct method to server