# Get multiple arrays of mongodb documents and merge them for unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, array-merge

I need to get all tags, which are stored in an array for multiple documents. I can select all needed documents by:

```
Collection.find({ 'metadata.tags': { $exists: true } });
```

The data of the first document could look like

```
"metadata" : {
    "type" : "photo",
    "tags" : [
        "test",
        "anything",
        "something",
        "more"
    ]
}
```

The second one:

```
"metadata" : {
    "type" : "photo",
    "tags" : [
        "different",
        "content",
        "something",
        "more"
    ]
}
```

Some of the elements in the arrays are duplicated. I need just unique values, so the result in this example would have six elements.

I would think of something like this for removing duplicates:

```
var c = a.concat(b);
var tags = c.filter( function (item, pos) { return c.indexOf(item) == pos; } );
return tags;
```

But my first problem is how to get access of all arrays, which could be more then just two, as the `find()` will give me multiple documents. How do I get the arrays of all documents and merge them?

The second problem is to remove duplicates, as my example would just work for two arrays.

**Update**

I would do something like this:

```
    var tags = [];
    Media.find({ 'metadata.tags': { $exists: true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
        tags = tags.concat(doc.metadata.tags);
    });
    var result = tags.filter( function (item, pos) { return tags.indexOf(item) == pos; } );
    return result;
```

Maybe this could be optimized...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your , mongoDB has already provided us a `distinct` command. Use it like below:

```
Collection.distinct('metadata.tags')
```

The above command will give you distinct values from the array. There wont be any duplicate elements. Hence your second problem will also be solved

Comment: Is it also part of minimongo as I'm using meteor?

Comment: I have worked in mongoose and mongodb native driver, both provides distinct method. By googling i found out that minimongo doesn't support distinct keyword. I can also give you an aggregate query as a workaround if it does support aggregation

Comment: see this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514733/does-meteor-have-a-distinct-query-for-collections

Comment: What do you think of my solution (please have a look at the updated post)?

Comment: looks fine to me, but in case of huge number of documents it can lead into performance issues

Comment: Thanks. What dimensions are 'huge numbers' - roughly?

Comment: That you have to simulate and find it out for yourself. It depends on a number of factors like your hardware, etc...